# Export all content from wordpress

Tags: database, migration, installation

Evening all.

I've decided instead of upgrading the install of wordpress that I have, to just take the content (my writeups, comments, pages) and move them to the new site install. Is there an easy way to do this at all, or would it just be simpler to just move the old DB to the new install?

For reference, I'm upgrading from v2.9 to the latest release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress already has this available under **Tools > Export**.

You can export all of your posts, comments, authors, etc. into an XML file which you can them Import into a new (or not new) installation.

I believe this has been part of the core since WordPress 2.1.

[image: Where to Find Export in WordPress]

Comment: Ugh I hate when I miss things right underneath my nose. Thanks for the info!